# Control an existing application with Python

Tags: python

I have been programming with Python for some time and noticed that it's possible to interact, for example, with MS Excel files through the library XLWT.

Now I would like to know if it's possible to use Python to control other applications, such as the **Calculator.exe** which is on the standard Windows path `C:\Windows\system32`.

Is there any way to write a script with Python, let's say, to make the calculator opening and executing `9+3=`? I usually like to write some code myself first and ask for help later,  but here I've no clue even if it's possible and my researches on Internet have yield only this script to launch the program:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe")
```

Any help, suggestion or even just "no, it's not possible" would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It will always depend on the cooperativity of the other program.  If it allows being tweaked, it will offer an API for this (and hopefully a documentation telling you how to use it).  This is not really a Python question because it rather depends on how the API is written.  If this API comes as a C library, you will have to write at least a bit of C code to access it via Python.  If it is a way of calling the program (special options, etc.) then Python will have as much or less trouble providing these as any other programming language.

Comment: @Alfe, alright. So let's say this (I'm sorry for any stupid question but I'm not a real programmer): if I'd like to programmatically repeat some behaviors of the Bloomberg interface (e.g.: writing a text, sending a file etc.), shall I look for the Bloomberg API as a Python library?

Comment: Having said that, for the calculator in Windows I'm pretty sure it offers the typical Windows API (called OLE, if I remember correctly) which also is used by copy & paste actions.  So I guess in this case it will be possible, but since Windows is not my domain, I cannot offer any help there.

Comment: I've no idea what Bloomberg is :-)  Gotta look that up ...

Comment: I've got your point. I looked a bit on the web and yes, you're right, I need an API offered by the company which is giving the software. Please write your first comment as an answer so I will mark it as my favourite one ;)

Comment: www.bloomberg.com?  So I guess you've got a software product accessing that financial stuff site.  Then, yes, try to find a Python-oriented API.  If you just find sth for C/C++ you can write an adaptor to access it via Python, but if you're not a programmer, be ready to learn a lot :)

Comment: I've just found the Python-oriented API, free access from Bloomberg for Bloomberg users, exactly what I've been looking for. But I told you, I'm not a programmer so I was missing the keyword "API" to even try looking for it on the web :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will always depend on the cooperativity of the other program. If it allows being tweaked, it will offer an API for this (and hopefully a documentation telling you how to use it).

This is not really a Python question because it rather depends on how the API is written. If this API comes as a C library, you will have to write at least a bit of C code to access it via Python. If it is a way of calling the program (special options, etc.) then Python will have as much or less trouble providing these as any other programming language.

Comment: For sake of completeness, the API I was looking for is `win32api` (to control the calculator or other Windows applications), while the library to control the Bloomberg software is `BLPAPI` which is free-of-charge available [here](http://www.openbloomberg.com/open-api/) in C, C++, Java, .NET, Perl and Python. Danke schon Alfe ;)